# jhipster EventSource request timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-webflux

I have a problem with javascript `EventSource` in jhipster. I used `EventSource` with Spring boot webflux in a normal spring boot application. I that project, when a user subscribe to `/chat/subscribe`, the connection keep open for long time of inactivity(I tested for 30 minutes). I don't use any configuration in my spring boot app. But when I use `EventSource` in jhipster app, the connection closes after exactly 2 minutes of inactivity. I don't know where jhipster set the configuration for this. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ChatResource {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ptpReplayProcessor")
    private ReplayProcessor<String> ptpReplayProcessor;

    @GetMapping(value = "/chat/subscribe", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Flux<String> subscribe() {
        return Flux.from(ptpReplayProcessor);
    }

}
```

ReplayProcessorConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ReplayProcessorConfig {

    @Bean("ptpReplayProcessor")
    ReplayProcessor<String> ptpReplayProcessor() {
        ReplayProcessor<String> replayProcessor = ReplayProcessor.create(0, false);
        replayProcessor.subscribe(new BaseSubscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void hookOnNext(String ptp) {
                System.out.println("ptp replay processor called!");
            }

        });
        return replayProcessor;
    }
}
```

Client Side(part of my componenet):

```
    ....
    this.source = new EventSource('http://localhost:9000/api/chat/subscribe');
    this.source.onmessage = event => {
        console.log(event);
    };
    this.source.onerror = event => {
        console.log('error');
    };
```

While messages sent and `ptpReplayProcessor.onNext(message)` called, the browser logs the messages and everything is right. But if I don't send any message for 2 minutes, browser console shows `error`!. I want to know why this problem exist in just jhipster and not in normal spring boot application!
Thank your for your attention.